# Twitter PI update profile banner

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am having trouble changing the banner image using tmhoauth. Everytime I post an image, whether it is locally hosted or from a URL I get the return code 422 - which would indicate that the size of the image file is too large or the dimensions are incorrect. This happens regardless of image size or dimensions. Any ideas? here is the code - I have removed tokens

```
<?php

$banner_image = 'image1.jpg';
$result = post_tweet($banner_image);
print "Response code: " . $result . "\n";
function post_tweet($banner_image) {
    require_once('tmhOAuth.php');
    print "Posting...\n";
    $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
        'consumer_key' => '---',
        'consumer_secret' => '---',
        'user_token' => '---',
        'user_secret' => '---',
        'curl_ssl_verifypeer'   => false
    )); 

    $connection->request('POST', $connection->url('1/account/update_profile_banner'), array('banner'=>$banner_image), true, true);

    return $connection->response['code'];
}
?>
```

RESOLVED: 
Thankyou @bdares! for anyone else who make this silly mistake or needs help with update_profile_banner code as follows:

```
$banner_image = 'image1.jpg';
$result = post_tweet($banner_image);
print "Response code: " . $result . "\n";
function post_tweet($banner_image) {
    require_once('tmhOAuth.php');
    print "Posting...\n";
    $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
        'consumer_key' => '---',
        'consumer_secret' => '---',
        'user_token' => '---',
        'user_secret' => '---',
        'curl_ssl_verifypeer'   => false
    )); 

    $connection->request('POST', $connection->url('1/account/update_profile_banner'), array('banner'=>'banner'=>"@{$banner_image};type=image/jpeg;filename={$banner_image}"), true, true);

    return $connection->response['code'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You're sending in a string into what should be a file parameter?

Comment: Thanks bdares, forgot to change to file. Oops :) Updated